# How to run method from inner class in Android?

Tags: java, android

Hello stackoverflow people. I've got following code.

```
public class ChangeActivity extends Activity {
EditText myTextBox;

void doProcessing(){ /*do something*/ }
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  myTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextBox);
  myTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int before, int count) {
     doProcessing();
   }
  });
 }
}
```

The problem is: I can't access doProcessing() from onTextChanged(). How to resolve it? I need doProcessing for other pieces of code, so I'd like not to put it inside onTextChanged().

Comment: Actually from your code, you can simply access it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the outer class from the inner class using the class name and `this`. For example:

```
ChangeActivity.this.doProcessing();
```

Comment: I don't think that syntax is required in the case above though... Unless of course TextWatcher also has a doProcessing() method I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN access methods from the outer class in the inner class.

Alan's correct on the OuterClass.this syntax BUT you only have to use it if you need to disambiguate between methods with the same name. You don't need to do that in this instance.

To illustrate my point, this simplified but equivalent code compiles just fine...

```
public class Temp {
    void foo() { }

    public void bar() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                foo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So... When you say you can't access it, what do you mean?